# Use Web API from ASP.NET or Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've been looking into using Web API for a new product I'm developing; the initial version will be a web application followed up by mobile/tablet applications so the Web API route seems a good one.

I've read a lot about securing Web APIs using cryptography and SSL, however one thing I'm not too clear on is where to call the Web API from.

If I'm using private cryptography to create an authentication token it seems to make sense to create the HTTP request using ASP.NET leveraging HttpClient etc. as the web server will have a private encryption key so the Web API which will have a corresponding private key will know the request came from the website.

This makes sense going forward as a mobile/table app will have a separate key etc.

Sounds silly, but it seems to me that the browser client cannot do the encrypting as the private key would be visible to the user relatively easily and they could take that key and use it elsewhere, (mobile/tablet clients would be able to do the encrypting as the key could be embedded).

Fair enough, but if I'm posting back to my web-server to do the encrypting I'm essentially sending the details of my request to the server un-encrypted, so someone could take the request sent to the web server, change it and the server would encrypt and send the changes to the Web API.

Is there a way to send encrypted Web API requests from the client (javascript) without revealing the key? Am I right about the server requests? will SSL sort out that problem?

I think I'm confusing myself slightly with all the information out there about securing Web APIs, any clarity would be welcome!

Comment: If your dealing with any "secure" information you should always use SSL anyway. I do agree that trying to do anything with private keys on the browser is a no-no

Comment: Well it's not "secure data" in anyway that's going to matter, we aren't dealing with credit card numbers or sensitive personal information, but we don't want unauthorised users to access the API. We do plan to use SSL for the website; I suppose I'm wondering whether there's much point implementing a lot of extra authentication if we are using SSL apart from avoiding "repeat requests".